# ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException?

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I know this is fairly simple, but I cannot figure out why I keep getting the out of bounds exception. I have tried initializing the arrays in different ways and that still does not help. I get the exception at the toString method, and at the portion that checks to see if the day is within the correct range of the month its defined for.

```
public class MyDate 
{
//variables for year day and month.
private int year, day, month;

//variable for n which is used to compare to the days for leap years.
int n;

String[] Months = {"January","Feburary","March","April","May","June","July"
                ,"August" ,"September","October","November","December"};
int[] MaxDays = {31,31,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

public MyDate(int year, int day, int month)
{      
    //Checks to see if the year is valid.
    if (year < 1600 || year > 3000)
    {
        System.out.println("The year entered is not valid, "
                + "You entered: " + year);
        System.out.println("The year must be between 1600 and"
                + " 3000.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    //Checks to see if the month is valid.
    if (month < 1 || month > 12)
    {
        System.out.println("The month is not valid, " + "You Entered: "
                + month);
        System.out.println("The month must be between 1 and 12.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    //Checks to see if the day is valid
    if (day >= MaxDays[this.day - 1])
    {
        advance();
    }
    //Checks for a leap year, and if the day is valid or not.
    if ((year %  400 == 0) || (year % 100 != 0))
    {   
           if (year % 4 == 0)
            {
                if (month == 2)
                {   
                    //Loops that goes from 27-31 comparing the day to n.

                    int n = 27;
                    do
                    {
                        if (n == day)
                        {
                            System.out.println("This is a leap year, and you entered " + n + " as the day"
                                    + "\n" + "this day is not valid for a leap year");
                            System.out.println();
                            break;
                        }

                        if (n == 32)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        n++;
                    }
                    while (n == day);

                    }
                }
    }
    else    
    {
        this.year=year;
        this.day=day;
        this.month=month;
    }
}

//Checks to see if two dates are equal to eachother.
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    if (obj instanceof MyDate){
        MyDate d = (MyDate)obj;
        if (this.getMonth()==d.getMonth() && this.getDay()==d.getDay() &&
            this.getYear()==d.getYear())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}

//gives a general format for the month day and year.
public String toString()
{
    return Months[month - 1] + " " + day + "," + year + "";
}
```

Comment: Have you run this in a debugger?  That is usually the easiest way to find these things

Comment: Please post the entire text of the exception and mark which line of your code it complains about.

Comment: change MaxDays[this.day-1] to MaxDays[month-1];

Comment: Looks like you have many errors here.  I think this is another one: In `toString()`, this would be failing `Months[month - 1]`. Reason: `this.month` defaults to 0.  You pass and validate `month` in your constructor, but you only ever set `this.month=month` if this expression is false `if ((year %  400 == 0) || (year % 100 != 0))`. So you end up trying to access `Months[-1]`.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at MyDate.toString(MyDate.java:120)
 at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.PrintStream.println(Unknown Source)
 at MyDate.MyDateDemo(MyDate.java:145)
 at MyDate.main(MyDate.java:167)                                                        this was the whole exception, I fixed the one with the maxdays, but the other tostring method is still failing.

Comment: and yes i have run it in the debugger, I still cant figure out why its doing it.

Comment: @Marcus Scaffidi See my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is coming from there

```
if (day >= MaxDays[this.day - 1])
```

where `this.day = 0`

I suppose you should pass `month` instead.

```
if (day >= MaxDays[month - 1])
```

**UPDATE**
In your `toString()` method `month` = 0 because you did not set month before.
Do `this.month=month;` outside of `else` block in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks alot!! My whole problem was having the this.year=year; and so on in the else statement, and it wasnt setting the correct values, they were just setting to 0 automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error is here, in your `if condition`

```
 if (day >= MaxDays[this.day - 1])
```

> MaxDays[] is an array with 12 elements - index 0 - 11

`days can be from 1-31,` so if `day is greater than 12, it will give an IndexOutOfBoundException.`

In your code though it would be always zero since you are not initializing it before using it.

Comment: `this.day` is always 0 in this line and `day` can be any number in this constructor. So the problem is in `this.day` but not in `day`.

Comment: @Alex agreed. Edited.